# Make a custom div shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

How to make a div like this? Any ideas please.

[image]

Here's my code so far: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpzqeu74/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Lpzqeu74)

```css
.triangle-up-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 15px 0 0;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.category-span {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="category-span">Category</span><span class="triangle-up-left"></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `clip-path`

[Support browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

Example

```css
.category-span {
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 86% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 86% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="category-span">Ecommerce</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick solution, try it:

```css
#shape {
  border-top: 100px solid black;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  width: 300px;
}
#text {
  margin-top: -70px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
<div id="text">Category</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With CSS [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) you can create flexible triangle which can expand to fit the container height.

```css
.category-span {
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.category-span:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #000 50%, transparent 50%);
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="category-span">Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce</span>
  <span class="category-span">Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce </span>
  <span class="category-span">Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce Ecommerce </span>
</div>
```